# Comparar valor em cada posição da String no Java?

Tags: java, string, comparação

Estou tendo dificuldades em comparar um valor em cada posição de uma `String`, segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
parametro = "30,60,90";
private int countVirgulas(String parametro) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= parametro.length(); i++) {
        if (parametro.substring(i).equals(",")) {
            count += count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Por exemplo eu tenho uma `String` com o valor "30,60,90".

Gostaria de comparar em cada posição dela e onde tiver vírgula, e incrementar no `count`.

No exemplo acima o `count` me retorna 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O principal problema parece ser o incremento que não está ocorrendo. No momento está adicionando ao `count` o próprio `count` que inicialmente vale 0, então ele nunca vai sair deste valor. O operador de auto adição deve ser usado com valores que não sejam neutros, senão o valor não será mudado. Mesmo que começasse com 1, a contagem iria progredindo geometricamente, o que não é o desejado, cada passo deve somar sempre 1 e não a última contagem. É mais simples que isto, basta usar o operador de incremento que equivale a fazer `count += 1`.

Outra mudança que eu faria por questões de performance é pegar o caractere ao invés da *substring*:

```
private int countVirgulas(String parametro) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parametro.length(); i++) {
        if (parametro.charAt(i) == ',') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xoPBFL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ogcmrxhi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/CompareChar.java).

Ou se preferir:

```
private int countVirgulas(String parametro) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char caractere : parametro.toCharArray()) {
        if (caractere == ',') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7OQrqW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fhquwzeh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/CompareChar2.java).

Se quiser usar o `substring()` tem que acertar um erro, já que ele não está pegando um caractere de cada vez:

```
private int countVirgulas(String parametro) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parametro.length(); i++) {
        if (parametro.substring(i, i + 1).equals(",")) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cyWbrs). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/advgosss-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/CompareChar3.java).

Comment: Obrigado bigown, no meu caso com o substring nem estava entrando no if e depois vi que coloquei count += count e que era para usar o count++, utilizando o charAt(i) funcionou corretamente, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de a pergunta já ter sido respondida, gostaria de lhe deixar uma outra maneira de implementar o contador de vírgulas utilizando um método interessante da classe `String` como forma de você poder ganhar mais visibilidade do que esta classe pode te oferecer.

```
public class ContadorDeVirgulas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(contadorDeVirgulas("30,60,90"));
    }

    public static int contadorDeVirgulas (String parametroComVirgula) {
        String[] parametroSeparado;
        int count = 0;

        //método que separa as strings de acordo com padrão que vc deseja, no seu caso, a vírgula
        parametroSeparado = parametroComVirgula.split(",", 100);

        //parametroSeparado.length retorna o tamanho do array de String após a remoção das vírgulas
        //o -1 foi usado para retirar da contagem o primeiro valor (30), pois não há vírgula antes dele
        count = parametroSeparado.length - 1;

        //retorno do contador
        return count;
    }

}
```

Nesta implementação utilizei o método `split` da classe `String`. Esse método divide uma string em partes de acordo com uma [`regex` (expressão regular)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html/).

O código está comentado, para vê-lo em funcionamento, veja pelo [Ideone](http://ideone.com/yXkTkf).

Para mais referências sobre esse métodos, segue abaixo algumas leituras que recomendo:

[Java - String split() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)
Fonte: [tuturialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/)

[Documentação Java sobre o método `split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))
Fonte: [Docs Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/)

[Documentação sobre Regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
Fonte: [Docs Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/)

Comment: Eu até votaria na resposta se ela fosse mais simples. Basta uma linha pra fazer isto: `return parametroComVirgula.split(",").length - 1;`. Ela não tá errada, pelo contrário, mas sugere uma complicação desnecessária. Ainda que a intenção possa ter sido o didatismo, no fim acaba acontecendo o contrário e as pessoas podem achar que precisa fazer um método enorme assim.

Comment: Entendi, como vc disse, com uma linha já simplificaria tudo, só quis mostrar dessa forma para ele ver que existem outras maneiras em java para se fazer, como ele está começando agora para ele ver que pra um problema existem muitas maneiras de se resolver e tb mostrei alguns links de referência de onde procurar por informações extras conforme ele for evoluindo nos estudos dele.